# PHP Post not submitting all information?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a form which posts to submit the information to insert into a database, this part works as expected with all data returned.

However I also have a 'test' function for the insert to ensure that the information provided is valid and works as intended before inserting into the database, this is handled through ajax, The function for this is as follows:

```
function test()
{
    var arr= {};
    $('.arr').each(function(i, obj) {

            arr[obj.name] = $(this).val();
    });
    $("label").html("Started!");
    $.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            url: "test.php",
            data: arr,
            success: function(msg)
                {
                    $(test).html(msg);
                    $("label").html("Finished!");
                }
            });
}
```

However, when you `print_r` the `$_POST` or `$var` it does not return all fields. it only returns the following:

```
Array ( [a] => aaaaaa [b] => a [c] => \ [d] => \ [e] => \<\/span\> [f] => a )
```

c,d & e all contain some html code that is required to be stored however all come out blank, I tried to 'escape' them using the backwards slash however as seen above this now just posts' the '\' to the testing page, the post to the SQL insert page is working successfully with no issues so I'm sorts of stumped why it's not properly working, does anyone have any ideas?

Just editing in all ajax used etc:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />   
<link href="../style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.autocomplete.js'></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#name').keyup(username_check);
    createCourse($(".check_dom"))
});

function username_check(){

var username = $('#name').val();

jQuery.ajax(
        {

           type: "POST",
           url: "check_name.php",
           data: 'name='+ username,
           cache: false,
           success: function(response)
            {
            if(response == 1)
                {

                    $('#name').css('border', '3px #C33 solid'); 
                    $('#tick').hide();
                    $('#cross').fadeIn();
                }
            else
                {

                    $('#name').css('border', '3px #090 solid');
                    $('#cross').hide();
                    $('#tick').fadeIn();
                }

            }
        });
}
function createCourse(els)
    {
        els.autocomplete("check.php", 
            {
                width: 260,
                matchContains: true,
                mustMatch: true,
                selectFirst: false
            });

                els.result(function(event, data, formatted)
            {

            });
    };
function test()
    {
        var arr= {};
        $('.name').each(function(i, obj) {

                arr[obj.name] = $(this).val();
        });
        $("label").html("Started!");
        $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                url: "test.php",
                data: arr,
                success: function(msg)
                    {
                        $(test).html(msg);
                        $("label").html("Finished!");
                    }
                });
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Please share your html ?

Comment: That has the same result as above Saty.

Also raveenanigam, the html on this page is just a simple form, the form does work & the post works to another page, it just doesn't seem to work for the 'test' function which is called using:

<a href="javascript:;" onClick=test()>Test</a>

Comment: Have you checked the values with a client-side debugger like e.g. firebug?

Comment: Is `console.log(arr)` returns correct array with all data?

Comment: I haven't didn't think to do this as the form submit works as intended, the submit posts it to another PHP page to conduct the inserting into the SQL tables required. Will have a look at that now thanks..


Just looked with firefox all it reports as coming back from that script is "Array ([arr]=>[object Object].

Comment: What about serialize()?

Comment: as in http://api.jquery.com/serialize/ ;-)

Comment: No luck with that either @VolkerK. The weirdest part is I have another script that uses the same functions and works as intended is pretty much identical to this. Just stumped why it isn't working the same way.

Comment: I'd start with firebug (or the respective devtools in ie and chrome. And safari?), checking the (ajax) request in the network tab first. Did your browser send the data as expected or not?

Comment: The response from Firebug / Firefox is that it reports for print_r ($_POST_ is just
 "Array( [arr] => [object Object] ) "

Comment: Go to the network tab and check the request that has been sent for your `$.ajax(...)` code. There should be a tab for the payload of that request. Is your data in that request body?

Comment: The post request just reports 'Parameters - arr [object Object] ' then the source is 'arr=%5Bobject+Object%5D'  So it seems it's not posting the information within Firefox/ firebug. Yet for Chrome it does return some of the data (what is contained in the original post).

Comment: Could you share how your $(.arr) looks like? What is the DOM structure?

Comment: I've just updated  the original post to display all the ajax used on the page,  the check_name & check scripts work as intended it is just  the test that does not want to work correctly at this time.

Answer (score 0):

For a better compatible code,
Replace in your code:

```
$('.arr').each(function(i, obj) {
    arr[obj.name] = $(this).val();
});
```

with:

```
$('.arr').each(function(i, obj) {
     arr.push({obj.name: $(this).val()==""?$(this).val():$(this).html()});
});
```

Now to your real question:
Unless you some of your objects are not of types that hold value, you could use html() check if value is empty like I did.

But to be more specific, if it is working fine to another page but not just the test.php page, then 98% chances are your error is in test.php or your header sent.

Comment: Thanks for the ammendment, my test page currently only has a function call and "print_r ($_POST)" on it to see what is being received at this time.

One interesting thing I've just found though (possibly through a change somewhere not sure what one which isn't helpful)  is  the firebug console does report that the array response for test.php now does include all of the correct fields.. However the page still just displays c,d & e with '\' etc.